# Proof of Law of Iterated Expectation for discrete case

Tags: probability, proof-verification

One of the Law of Iterated Expectations states that
$$E\left( E\left( X\mid G \right)\mid H \right)=E \left( X\mid H \right),$$
where $H\subseteq G$. 
My "desperate attempt" of proof goes like this. 
$$\begin{align*}
E\left( E\left( X\mid G \right)\mid H \right) &=\sum_{h\in H } \left( E\left( X\mid G \right)\mid H=h \right)P \left(H=h \right)\\
&=\sum_{h\in H}\left( \sum_{x\in X\mid G }x\cdot P\left((X\mid G)=x\mid H=h \right)\right)P \left(H=h \right)\\
&=\sum_{h\in H}\left( \sum_{x\in X\mid G }x\cdot P\left((X\mid G)=x, H=h \right)\right).\\
\end{align*}
$$

Since $H\subseteq G$, I believe that the set of values that $X\mid H$ can take is a subset of the values that $X\mid G$ can take. Furthermore,
$$\begin{align*}
P(X\mid G=x,H=h)=
\begin{cases}
P((X\mid H)=x, H=h)&, \text{if $x\in (X\mid H) \cap (X\mid G)$},\\ 
0 &,\text{if $x\notin (X\mid H) \cap (X\mid G)$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

Consequently, 
$$\begin{align*}
E\left( E\left( X\mid G \right)\mid H \right) &=\sum_{h\in H}\left( \sum_{x\in X\mid H }x\cdot P\left((X\mid G)=x, H=h \right)+ \sum_{x\notin X\mid H }x\cdot P\left(X\mid G=x, H=h \right) \right)\\
&=\sum_{h\in H}\left( \sum_{x\in X\mid H }x\cdot P\left((X\mid H)=x, H=h \right) \right)\\
&=\sum_{x\in X\mid H}x P((X\mid H)=x)\\
&=E \left( X\mid H \right)
\end{align*}.
$$

I feel very conflicted when I claim 
$$\begin{align*}
E((X\mid G)\mid H=h)=\sum_{x\in X\mid G }x\cdot P\left((X\mid G)=x\mid H=h \right).\\
\end{align*}
$$
Is my "attempt on proof" correct? If it is not, where did I go wrong and how can I fix the error? Thanks in advance for the read and feedback.

Comment: Are $G$ and $H$ random variables or sets of discrete values (as implied by $H\subseteq G$)?

Comment: @Graham Kemp. Thank you for the answer. I wanted to express that $H$ captures less information than $G$ and  honestly thought I could write it as $H \subseteq G$. However, after you pointed that out, I believe I am mistaken. What conditions should I replace it with then?